# How to represent a tree structure with ORDER BY OR GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a table 'TEMPLATES'(with columns ID,NAME,IS_MASTER,MASTER_ID etc) which describes multiple content management system elements e.g. masters, templates etc.
The column IS_MASTER filters the master-docs. I want to filter all master-docs and the associated elements(documents), which point to the master over the 'MASTER_ID' column of the same table but I want to order the rows one after another for example after a result row which shows a master should be listed the elements, which point to this master (and not all rows mixed up like in the screenshot) :

[image]

But I can only do it in this way, I don't know how to order or group by

```
SELECT x.*,x.ROWID FROM TEMPLATE x
WHERE IS_MASTER IN (1) OR MASTER_ID IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
select *
from templates
order by nvl(master_id, id);
```

This would tell the database to sort by master_id, and if that column is empty (NULL) to use the id. This way the master and its children are sorted together.

Alternatively you can use a hierarchical query:

```
select *
from templates
start with master_id is null
connect by master_id = prior id;
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know either one or the other functions, but the second query orders the rows in the desired way! The first makes it 90%.